# Thread not run immediately when using more than 4 BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I use multiple `BackgroundWorker` control to run some task as multithreading. But I found that when using more than 4 BackgroundWoker, the one from 4th forward delay more than second to actually execute from when calling `RunWorkerAsync`.

Could help me how can I start all backgroundworker immediately?

```
class TaskLog
{
    public int task_id;
    public DateTime call_time;
    public DateTime start_time;
    public DateTime end_time;
}

BackgroundWorker[] bws = new BackgroundWorker[18];
int[] tasks = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Queue<TaskLog> queueTask;
TaskLog[] records;
int task_complete = 999;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (task_complete < tasks.Length) return;

    task_complete = 0;

    records = tasks.Select(t => new TaskLog { task_id = t }).ToArray();
    queueTask = new Queue<TaskLog>(records);

    for (int i = 0; i < bws.Length && queueTask.Count > 0; ++i)
    {
        bws[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
        bws[i].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(download_vid_work);
        bws[i].RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(download_vid_complete);

        var x = queueTask.Dequeue();
        x.call_time = DateTime.Now;

        bws[i].RunWorkerAsync(x);
        //Debug.WriteLine("start " + x.task_id);
    }
}

void download_vid_work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var record = (TaskLog)e.Argument;
    record.start_time = DateTime.Now;
    //Debug.WriteLine("actually start " + record.task_id);

    Thread.Sleep(10000); // 10s
    e.Result = record;
}

void download_vid_complete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var record = (TaskLog)e.Result;
    record.end_time = DateTime.Now;
    //Debug.WriteLine("complete " + item.ToString());

    ++task_complete;
    if (task_complete == tasks.Length)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("all tasks are completed!");
        foreach (var r in records)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("task {0} delay time: {1}", r.task_id, (r.start_time - r.call_time).TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0,0"));
        }
    }
    else if (queueTask.Count > 0)
    {
        var bw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        var nextTask = queueTask.Dequeue();
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(nextTask);
        nextTask.call_time = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Here is log result after run:

```
all tasks are completed!
task 1 delay time: 22
task 2 delay time: 24
task 3 delay time: 24
task 4 delay time: 23
task 5 delay time: 1,005
task 6 delay time: 2,002
task 7 delay time: 3,003
task 8 delay time: 4,003
task 9 delay time: 5,004
task 10 delay time: 6,005
```

Comment: You cannot have an infinite number of threads and expect them all to run. You have probably got 4 cores and they are all processing a thread, the others have to wait for a gap in resource before they can run. One of the fallacies of multithreading is just adding lots of threads makes things quicker, oftentimes it can make things slower!

Comment: @Belogix: Windows schedules threads of the same priority round-robin, and last I checked the quantum for a thread was around 50ms. So while exceeding the number of cores would delay thread startup by a small amount, it would not be enough to account for the one second delay reported here. The fifth thread would have to wait at most 50 more milliseconds before one of the initial threads got pre-empted and allow that fifth one to run.

Comment: Microsoft made a design mistake in the BackgroundWorker class, nobody ever uses it in a scenario where a threadpool thread is ideal.  But they are also very good at fixing their mistakes, you should be using the Task class instead.  You can use the TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning option to fix your problem.  Do beware that your code is very fake, you do need to experiment with your real code.

Comment: I'm using .Net 3.5 which not support Task. Why is BackgroundWorker a design mistake, I'm very suprised because there are many people recommend to use it on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ThreadPool` class, which manages the thread pool threads used for `BackgroundWorker` (and other needs), does not maintain an infinite number of worker threads ready to run.

You can configure the actual number of idle threads (*), using the `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()` method. As you can see in your case, when you initially start your program, there are four idle threads ready to accept work right away. The default number of idles threads depends on a variety of things related to the OS version and configuration.

Once there are more queued work items for the thread pool than there are threads to service them, the `ThreadPool` class does not create new threads right away. It waits for a short period of time (as you can see from your test, one second), on the assumption that it's *possible* one of the other tasks may finish soon and it will be able to reuse that thread rather than going to all the trouble of creating yet another thread (which incurs its own overhead and would even slow down the work of the threads already running).

In general, you should avoid overriding the default values for the thread pool, as they are generally set correctly given your OS version, hardware, etc. For example, it won't help to have more CPU-bound threads running than you have CPU cores on the machine. Letting the `ThreadPool` class decide when and how to run your worker threads is usually the best approach.

**(*)** The above is a bit of an over-simplification. In newer versions of .NET, the minimum number of threads may or may not actually exist at any given time. If work items are queued when there are fewer than the minimum number, `ThreadPool` will immediately create new threads as needed up to the minimum. Beyond that, it then shifts to its more elaborate creation and scheduling logic.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yes it does properly handle CPU-bound tasks. But when my scenario is IO bound, i.e., I'd spin up 100 tasks, handling 100 IO channels, but each require little CPU work. In this case, would the low thread pool min thread count still a reasonable preset?

Comment: @KFL: I/O is somewhat different. There is a separate thread pool for IOCP. IOCP is designed such that you don't need _nearly_ as many threads as there are outstanding I/O operations, because threads are only woken when an I/O operation actually completes. Frankly, the default values in .NET are almost always what you want. People working on super-large-scale implementations may find custom values helps a little, but it takes a lot more than what can be explained in a Stack Overflow comment to cover how one would approach that.