# Background worker questions

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, .net-3.5, backgroundworker

Can multiple (19 in fact) background workers all use the same DoWork event? Is there an issue with this?

```
var bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw1.DoWork += DoingStuff_DoWork;
var bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw2.DoWork += DoingStuff_DoWork;
var bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw3.DoWork += DoingStuff_DoWork;
```

My next question is, if I call RunWorkerAsync on each background worker, will they all start at the same time?

```
bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
bw2.RunWorkerAsync();
bw3.RunWorkerAsync();
```

I'm having some issues with a machine vision application which is driving me nuts.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need bw2 and bw3 if their DoWork is empty? You did not register work for them to execute... It's all in bw1. Btw, minor typo on var bw2 -> var bw3.

Comment: Shoot, you're right. That's a typo. It is supposed to be bw1.DoWork bw2.DoWork and so on... My mistake sorry

Comment: It entirely depends on the contents of the `DoingStuff_DoWork`... Depending on what is in there will tell you if you can have multiple threads executing that code simultaneously.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to start using Threads directly to get my desired result. I just liked the little extra abstraction using the backgroundworker provides.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this **BUT** you have no control over when a worker is run.

You may want to redesign and use [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx), which is more suited to your needs.

Comment: I wish I could convince our tech director to move up to .Net 4 for that exact reason. Id waaaaaay rather use tasks than using threads...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a number of BackgroundWorker DoWork to execute the same function. Remember that each DoWork event is invoked on a separate thread so you might run into a threading problem such as data races, dead lock or live lock.

Besides, using the same function would also make debugging more difficult as if you put a breakpoint somewhere in the function, you need to determine which thread fires the event. Thus, unless the function is relatively simple, I suggest that you hook your DoWork event to a different event handler, put common code into one function and have it called inside the event function.

Your issue with threads not firing at the same time has been answered here
[Thread not run immediately when using more than 4 BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142664/thread-not-run-immediately-when-using-more-than-4-backgroundworker?lq=1)

Comment: Each DoWork event is passed a unique key value, so determining which thread I'm in isn't overly difficult. My biggest issue is, not all threads are firing at the same (or even close) time.

Comment: Your issue with threads not firing at the same time has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142664/thread-not-run-immediately-when-using-more-than-4-backgroundworker

Comment: @AceK47 I updated my answer, was that of any help to you?